# Should I display multiple looping and autoplaying videos on a website using videos or GIFs?

Tags: performance, video, html5-video, animated-gif

On my website, I'm trying to display multiple videos that will autoplay at the same time. These videos will autoplay when scrolled into view, and should loop infinitely.

The videos are around 1 minute long each and should loop and autoplay when scrolled into view.

An example of this is in the image below.

I'm aware that this is poor user experience in general, but in this case, it makes sense because it's multiple angles of the same event - and one is more primary than the others (shown as the largest one).

[image: Multiple videos playing at the same time]

From a page load and performance perspective, would it make sense for all of these to be played as videos, gifs, or a combination thereof? Is it even possible to have multiple videos playing at the same time using HTML 5 video?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Most advice these days tends to be to use streamed video rather than animated gifs as gifs can be very large and can slow down your page loading.

It will depend on the video format and quality and the machine the browser is running on but most devices/browsers will handle a layout like you have shown above with a common video encoding and packaging, e.g. h.264 and mp4 etc.

The reason the format of the video makes a difference is that browsers will generally make use of HW acceleration for video decoding if the browser and machine support it.

If you are interested, you can see on Chrome, for example, the video decoding capability by entering the folling in the browser (at the time of writing):

> chrome://gpu/

This will give you information like this:
[image]

[image]

If you have multiple videos you may find that the HW acceleration is limited and can't be applied to them all in which case you may find the video slowing down. In fact, having ***a lot*** of videos on the browser will definitely slow it down one way or the other but if your solution is only 4 videos you will probably find you are ok on most devices.

Comment: When you say: 

"If you have multiple videos you may find that the HW acceleration is limited and can't be applied to them all"

Is there some way I can find out the number of videos that tips over the limit?

Comment: @WillMcLean - I am not aware of any reliable method beyond trial and error. Some platforms may have some indications but even these may need some experiment to determine who they act for a given use case - see this answer for any example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36360718/334402